# DragNDrop upload: put file dropped into file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I just followed [this tutorial](http://www.maximechaillou.com/simple-upload-en-drag-and-drop-avec-html5-jquery-php/) to create a drag'n'drop upload system (it is in french, but I use the same code).

It works very well, but it works with an Ajax request.
I'd like to make it works differently: I'd like to make it works with a `<input type="file"/>`.
I fact, I want that when a file is dropped, it is "added" in the input like if we did it with the input only.

Is it even possible to make it ?

Thank you!

Comment: remove this from drop listener: // Main function to upload
upload(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);

Comment: yes, but then what to do ?

Comment: add a submit button to the form
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp